# Не работают сесии на сайте

Tags: php, сессия

Доброго времени господа знатоки) такая проблема поставила меня в тупик - делал я много сайтов на всех использовал один и тот же скрипт запуска и записи данных в сессии а именно

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 ?>
```

так запускаю - документ сохранен в ютф- без бом(!) - все как полагается сессия запускается в сааааамом начале документа - перед функцией запуска нету ни одного символа тут все по фэншую

записываю в сессию вот так

```
  $_SESSION['passw'] = "паролль к примеру"; 
  $_SESSION['login'] = "ну логин к примеру";
```

проверяю допустим так

```
  if (!empty($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['passw'])) {  }
```

и не работает( при том - на локальном хосте - все работает идеально - на 20ти других сайтов работает тоже один и тот же этот скрипт!

замечу что этот сайт на котором не работает сей простой скрипт - находится на совершенно другом хостинге чем те 10 сайтов на которых все работает (не говорю уже об ЛХ) хостинг панель rshost (если это поможет) предоставлен видимо ISPsystem © 1997-2015 (в копирайте написано) я в начале думал что просто в тупую на хосте отключены сессии НО до этого на хосте стоял старый сайт на джумле и там все было настроено через сессии и все вроде как работало, я в тупике господа подскажите пожалуйста - вдруг кто то с похожим сталкивался?

Забыл возможно это важно!
после того как юзер авторизуется и через пост передаются логин пароль в обработчик (который на этой же странице что и форма) для проверки - после того если проверка прошла и данные заносятся в сессию - страница обновляется
через js так

```
 ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Поздравляю вы успешно авторизовались!');
        location.href="";
        </script>
        <?php
```

что бы очистить переменные POST

Comment: Если убрать этот js с обновлением страницы то сессия работает но при переходе на другую страницу или обновлении текущей сессии стираются(

Comment: При каждом входе на странцу `session_id()` меняется? Куки передаются от сервера к клиенту и обратно? Что-нибудь в error_log пишется?

Comment: да к стати что то я сам не подумал заглянуть туда ругается он вот так там [Sun Nov 22 00:02:06 2015] [error] [client 178.91.120.30] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/www/stomcol.kz/data/mod-tmp/sess_p89e3lr9q3q562k28jvdvg1nb1, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /var/www/stomcol.kz/data/www/stomcol.kz/index.php on line 2

Comment: Ну значит все просто. Надо создать нужную директорию и дать нужные права

Comment: тоесть просто пустую папку и в ней права сделать? я так понимаю в нее будут сохраняться куки сессий?

Comment: Да. Только не помню чтобы их называли куки сессий. Это просто _данные сессии_. А в куках хранится идентификатор сессии. Пожалуй оформлю диагностику и решения в виде ответа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31992/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and-dantelol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При подобных проблемах следует выяснить следующее:

1. **Включен-ли механизм передачи идентификаторов сессий на хостинге?** Вывести значение `session_id()` (если PHP собран без поддержки сессий будет выдана ошибка об отсутствии функции) или связаться с провайдером;
2. **Вызывается-ли функция `session_start()`?** Иногда бывает так, что старт сессии происходит в поключаемом при каком-либо условии файле или функции. Чтобы удостовериться можно создать перед сессией искуственную критическую ошибку или вывод контрольной строки в *error_log*;
3. **Появляются-ли в *error_log* новые ошибки?** При их появлении следует устранить причины их появления;
4. **Меняется-ли каждом входе на страницу значение функции `session_id()` в рамках одной сессии?** Если не меняется, то скорее всего данные сессии не сохраняются и в п. 2 будет соответствующая ошибка (невозможность записи в файл или если применяются другие механизмы хранения сессии могут быть проблемы записи в базу). Если меняется, то нужно переходить к следующему пункту;
5. **Передаются-ли куки от сервера к клиенту и обратно?** Нужно смотреть на HTTP-заголовки запроса `Cookie` и заголовки ответа `Set-Cookie` при помощи средств разработки браузера или при помощи сниффера (например *Wireshark* или *tcpdump*). Если они не передаются от браузера говорит о запрете их хранения в браузере. Если куки не передаются к браузеру говорит о том, что заголовки не передаются из-за того, что PHP-скрипт уже начал формировать контент страницы до начала сессии. Одна из причин, приводящих к этой проблеме - наличие [маркера последовательности байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) в начале PHP-скрипта.

Comment: да  session_id(); работает, и значение его не меняется - в error логе появляются ошибки каждый раз когда запускаю вида такого: [Mon Nov 23 00:03:18 2015] [error] [client 178.91.120.30] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/www/stomcol.kz/data/mod-tmp/sess_5t2cgdj2at32gc08gb77geieg3, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory

Comment: теперь стал ругаться в ерор логе так 
[Mon Nov 23 18:16:08 2015] [error] [client 178.91.120.30] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/www/stomcol.kz/data/mod-tmp) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: А если в set_cookie написано айди сессии и черз точку с запятой path = / и восклицательный знак? это значит, что путь неверный?

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема на сервере, попробуйте добавить в начало кода:

ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.free74092.cpsite.ru');

session_set_cookie_params(7200, "/", ".free74092.cpsite.ru", false, false);

Сам с этим целый час мучался...